# Экспорт определенных файлов phpstorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Есть комит и в нем показаны файлы, которые были изменены и т.п.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу выгрузить только эти файлы в отдельную дирректорию на своем ПК ? Может ли такое phpstorm, или придется делать ручками ?

Comment: не знаю умеет ли так шторм, но git так точно может

Comment: @ArchDemon не подскажете как ?

Comment: точно не подскажу. Пользуюсь tortoiseGit. Там это сделано через Экспорт коммита. Или экспорт отдельных файлов в коммите

Comment: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4541300/1891712) есть про git.

Comment: GIT_INDEX_FILE=$(git diff --name-only) && cp -R $GIT_INDEX_FILE ~/storage_folder/